# HTML 5 Upwork account integration

Tags: html, upwork-api

Is there any way to show my upwork profile on my webpage? ifrane does not work. If there is no ways to do this, I will just make screenshot of my profie and put them to tge page.

Comment: Have you checked out the [Upwork API Center](https://developers.upwork.com/)? I'm not familiar with Upwork myself, but it seems you can fetch your profile info [through the API](https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=python#public-profiles).

Comment: Simple solution: You could save the (complete) HTML of the page, serve it yourself, and use that in an iframe.

Comment: I'll try it after Upwork API, thx to everyone.

Comment: While that achieves the basics I suppose, that's not a dynamic way of solving the problem though, @KIKOSoftware. When his Upwork info changes in any way, Samer will have to repeat the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Upwork API and "[Get freelancer profile by key](https://developers.upwork.com/#public-profiles_get-profile-details)" API to fetch the details and integrate the data into your site.
To simplify the process, you could use one of Upwork's libraries - see [here](https://developers.upwork.com/#getting-started_libraries-and-tools).